# Did they have dorm mothers for finishing schools in the 19th century?

Tags: 19th-century, education, victorian

I'm currently writing a novel, and was doing a lot of research on 19th century finishing schools for young ladies. In my book, the girls need to stay on site or next to the finishing school. However, there's not much info on the details that I need to know.

I figured they would have some sort of dorm situation but I need to know if dorm mothers were a thing back then, or if the headmistress would handle taking care of the girls if they needed anything? The book is set in London, England around 1837- 1845.

Comment: The etymology for "dorm" suggests that it's a 20th Century abbreviation, primarily used in the US, so it's use would be anachronistic for mid-19th Century London.

Comment: More likely than dormitories I believe is a number of nearby boarding houses, run almost universally by elderly widows and a daughter or niece, for girls not already resident in the city. It's unlikely an elderly couple would run a boarding house for young girls; but for obvious reasons parents would always prefer an all female house. There is certainly a boys school nearby that a couple would have more success letting roos out for.

Comment: *Headmistress* is also likely to be a misnomer in this time period and situation. [An article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/175242?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) in the Journal of British Studies, *Schoolmistresses and Headmistresses: Elites and Education in Nineteenth-Century England* can detail the differences and provide a lot of background on the early private finishing schools as compared to the later, fuller education offered after your settings time frame.

Comment: Women schoolteachers (along with governesses, tutors, and similar roles) seem popular characters in novels of the period: Charlotte Brontë's Jane Eyre (1847) has elements and Villette (1853) is largely set in a Belgian school. So there are likely to be some fictional sources you could investigate: see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/School_story) for starting points.

Comment: This is a great question. It's not something you are likely to find in an average history textbook but it's something that we can research.